# Opencv 2.4 and 3.1: choose default one

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I searched for this but couldn't find a solution yet; kind of new to ubuntu. Currently I have both Opencv 2.4 and 3.1 on my machine. If I do

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

it will print out 3.1.0; but if I use Python and

```
print cv2.__version__
```

then it will give 2.4.8. I want to make 3.1 as the default one when I

```
import cv2
```

in Python. How do I do this?

**EDIT**:

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Opencv 3 through this: [script for installation](https://github.com/milq/scripts-ubuntu-debian/blob/master/install-opencv.sh). Opencv 2.4 was installed earlier in similar way. Currently if I check

```
/usr/local/lib
```

there are 2 sets of .so files: like libopencv_core.so and libopencv_core.so.3.1. Should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem during a caffe make.  Solved it by adding this to my /caffe/makefile.config: LIBRARY_DIRS := $(OPENCV_LIB) /usr/local/lib

where /usr/local/lib is where the OpenCV 3.3.1 libraries are that I want to use.

Without that statement, caffe make was using /usr/lib for OpenCV.  That folder is where I have OpenCV 2.4 libraries.